# D3.js spread squares along circle with force

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I want to spread squares with content along a circle with force() and collision, so the squares don't overlap each other and main circle. 
Any thoughts how to do this? Should I use links to do this?
Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/benderlio/usbq839m/3/
Sometimes it spread the squares fine, but most of the time the squares are shifted as on the img.

[image]

```
    var force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody(1130))
     // .force('link', d3.forceLink().links(links))
      .on("tick", function () {

        var k = this.alpha(),
          kg = k * .02,
          spaceAround = 0.04;

        //console.log('', nodes);

        nodes.forEach(function (a, i) {
                       ...
        });

        svg.selectAll("rect")
          .style("fill", function (d) {
            return "#ccc"
          })
          .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.x - d.width / 2;
          })
          .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.y - d.height / 2;
          });

        svg.selectAll("line")
          .attr("x2", function (d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr("y2", function (d) {
            return d.y;
          })

        svg.selectAll("circle.end")
          .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return d.y;
          })

      });
```

Thanks.

**UPD:**

Added a main fixed square, now it looks better. But looks like I have to do something with "collision order". The squares a flipped. Any thoughts how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: `lx` and `ly` are always `< 0`. what is the use of `idToNode`, `overlapCount`?

Comment: @rioV8 don't know about overlapCount and lx,ly. I just took that code for box collision. Removed idToNode

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the general way to solve this problem, but here are some ad hocs for better solution:

1. When you define "target points" for rects gravity algorithm, make them not on boundary of the circle, but some distance away.

   ```
   x = ((150 + radius) * Math.cos(angle)) + (width / 2) + offset; // Calculate the x position of the element.
   y = ((150 + radius) * Math.sin(angle)) + (width / 2) + offset; // Calculate the y position of the element.
   ```
2. If you want for rects to not collide with the circle, you need custom force. Since exact formula for rect-circle collision is not simple, perhaps, it is enough to treat rectangles as circles, so add this after `nodes.forEach(...)`:

   ```
   nodes.forEach(function(a) {
      const diag = Math.sqrt(a.width ** 2 + a.height ** 2) / 2;
      const rad = 150;
      const [cx, cy] = [500, 500];
      const [dx, dy] = [a.x - cx, a.y - cy];
      const dist = Math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2);
      const shift = Math.max(0, rad + diag - dist);
      a.x += shift * dx / dist;
      a.y += shift * dy / dist;
   })
   ```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I added the main square. Now it looks better, but have to do something with "square order". Can you have a look at the updated question?

Answer (score 1):

Your collision force is too strong. Make it a bit less.

```
              lx *= 0.3;
              ly *= 0.3;
```

The center rect can be added with

```
nodes.push( { x:500, y:500, width:300, height:300, fx:500, fy:500, center: true });
```

Drawing of the rects should now be filtered

```
  var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(nodes.filter(d => !d.center))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
```

And if you also draw the center rect you must add a class

```
  g.append("rect")
    .attr("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("fill", "#ccc" )
    .attr("width", d => d.width )
    .attr("height", d => d.height )
    .attr("rx", 10)
    .attr("ry", 10);
```

And in the tick function filter on the rects with the class

```
svg.selectAll("rect.node")
  .attr("x", d => d.x - d.width / 2 )
  .attr("y", d => d.y - d.height / 2 );
```

Add a test to ignore the center `rect`

```
          if (a.center) return;
```

Updated force code

```
        nodes.forEach(function (a, i) {
          if (a.center) return;  // ignore this node
          // Apply gravity forces.
          a.x += (a.gravity.x - a.x) * kg;
          a.y += (a.gravity.y - a.y) * kg;
          nodes.slice(i + 1).forEach(function (b) {
            dx = (a.x - b.x)
            dy = (a.y - b.y)
            adx = Math.abs(dx)
            ady = Math.abs(dy)
            mdx = (1 + spaceAround) * (a.width + b.width) / 2
            mdy = (1 + spaceAround) * (a.height + b.height) / 2
            if (adx < mdx && ady < mdy) {
              l = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
              lx = (adx - mdx) / l * k
              ly = (ady - mdy) / l * k

              lx *= 0.3;
              ly *= 0.3;

              // choose the direction with less overlap
              if (lx > ly && ly > 0) lx = 0;
              else if (ly > lx && lx > 0) ly = 0;
              dx *= lx
              dy *= ly
              a.x -= dx
              a.y -= dy
              b.x += dx
              b.y += dy
            }
          });
        });
```

**Edit**

A modification would be to make the movement independent of the distance of the rect centers. Only move a certain amount in the opposite direction of the other center.

The current method changes the nodes later in the list already to a new position and base the collision of next nodes on those new positions. Better is to calculate the movement first based on all the nodes for time N and at the end apply this movement. This is done in the force simulation by calculating/modifying the speed (`d.vx`, `d.vy`) of the node. The simulation will apply the speed on the tick.